# How to add a SpriteKit Particle File to current view AND allow dynamic change with device movement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I have created a simple `sks` particle file in my project,I would like to know A: how can I implement this particle in my view & how can I add the appropriate parameters so that the particles travel in the direction that the device is being held in, (very similar to iOS7 Dynamic Wallpapers for example), so in my case, if I have stones falling straight down and the device is tilted to the right, the stones should start falling with a different angle. I'd really appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually thinking about applying this effect to my own game as well. This is a crude answer and I haven't actually tried combining these two elements, but it should definitely give you some pointers.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) SKEmitterNode * starEmitter;
@property (strong,nonatomic) CMMotionManager * self.motionManager;

// Create your emitter
 NSString *starPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"startButtonDisappear" ofType:@"sks"];
 self.starEmitter = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:starPath];

// Create a motion manager
self.motionManager = [CMMotionManager new];
[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
```

In your update method, calculate the gravity vector and assign acceleration properties of the emitter.

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
  CMAccelerometerData* data = self.motionManager.accelerometerData;

  // You really don't want NSLogs in this method in a release build, by the way
  NSLog(@"x [%2.1f] y [%2.1f] z [%2.1f]",data.acceleration.x,data.acceleration.y,data.acceleration.z)

  CGVector gravity;

  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    gravity = CGVectorMake(data.acceleration.x, data.acceleration.y);
  } else {
    gravity = CGVectorMake(-data.acceleration.x, -data.acceleration.y);
  }

  CGFloat tmp = gravity.dy;
  gravity.dy = gravity.dx;
  gravity.dx = tmp;

  // self.physicsWorld.gravity = gravity;

  self.starEmitter.xAcceleration = gravity.x;
  self.starEmitter.yAcceleration = gravity.y;

  NSLog(@"Emitter acceleration set to [%+4.2f,%+4.2f]",gravity.dx,gravity.dy);
}
```